# Support .deb files for software installer GUI

Tags: software-installation

I decided to try Elementary OS, and I especially liked the following thing: When files are opening with the .flatpakref extension, a certain "software installer" opens, well, so, I liked it very much, and I want this utility to be maintained `.deb` packages

Comment: Apologies, I’m not quite understanding the question. Is this a feature request? 

Answer (score 2):

Given the shift away from debs to flatpacks I don't think this will get implemented. But there is [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/), which seems to be what you are asking for.

Hope this helps, regards,
CK

Answer (score 1):

@ckruse, I want to make a feature-request. That is, to simply add support for installing deb-packages in this program, because rejecting them sounds too strange: how will they abandon them? We'll have to redo the entire system.

Comment: Well, you can find the project at https://github.com/elementary/appcenter

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the software you want with "apt install" option. I found all software I needed that way without needing to manage any extra tool to manage deb files. Firefox, Kmail, VLC, Double Commander and Thunderbird and office software. I also tested dpkg and it also worked fine. Maybe not the the answer you wanted, but very easy to use.